# Import Issue In Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm working on standalone system that uses Jython. In web editor, I can write Python code, but I can't import any builtin library. I asked developer about fixing this problem, but they said that they have issues about their system and Jython. My question here is how I can import builtin libraries?

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named ast in <script> at line number 1
```

Any advice about this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Works for me when using Jython

Comment: @AnttiHaapala as I said, they have problem with using Jython with their system. For this reason, I'm looking for a way for writing python code.